# What is ClassName::create in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I ran into is this code:

```
run Athlete::Create do |op|
  return redirect_to op.model, notice: 'Athlete was successfully created.'
end
```

I'm used to the standard `ClassName.create(params)` options.

Any idea what the `ClassName::Create do |op|` is, or is even called?

Comment: Do you have `services` folder in your app? May it be a `Create` service that was put under `Athlete` namespace?

Comment: is the gem trailblazer installed?

Comment: Hey Slava I do not have a service folder. 

Sean I do have Trailblazer installed. From the answers below it looks like that is my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking at is a gem called [Trailblazer](https://github.com/trailblazer/trailblazer) which from their github states :

> Trailblazer provides new high-level abstractions for Ruby frameworks. It gently enforces encapsulation, an intuitive code structure and gives you an object-oriented architecture.

Comment: Thanks, you are correct. Just this small amount of information is super helpful! Please feel free to upvote the question so others can google it easier. I'll add some more content to the question now that I have an answer.

Comment: Cheers. Please feel free to mark this the correct answer if you are satisfied with it.

Answer (score 1):

> Any idea what the `ClassName::Create do |op|` is, or is even called?

It is just a normal message send with a block argument.

Ruby allows you to use `::` for message sends. IOW, the line you ask about is exactly the same as

```
ClassName.Create do |op|
```

However, that is actually not the code. *This* is what the code looks like:

> ```
> run Athlete::Create do |op|
>   return redirect_to op.model, notice: 'Athlete was successfully created.'
> end
> ```

Ruby allows you to leave out the parentheses for an argument list in a message send, so this is equivalent to

```
run(Athlete::Create) do |op|
  return redirect_to op.model, notice: 'Athlete was successfully created.'
end
```

It is sending the message `run` to `self` passing the expression `Athlete::Create` and a block as an argument.

Comment: I think it's `run(Classname::Create) { |op| ... }` actually.

Comment: Thanks for breaking this down. It looks like Trailblazer was the cause of all of this, which explains the use of this code in the first place! Thank you so much for explaining the block issue to. It's nice to see whats going on under the hood! Feel free to upvote. ;) I gave you an upvote, just to low to show :(